# Project Reactor. Mono.map() vs Mono.flatMap()

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

What is the principal difference between these in terms of `Mono`?
From the documentation, I read that `flatMap` acts asynchronous and `map` synchronous. But that doesn't really make sense for me b/c Mono is all about parallelism and that point isn't understandable. Can someone rephrase it in a more understandable way?

Then in the documentation for `flatMap` stated (https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Transform the item emitted by this Mono asynchronously, returning the 
value emitted by another Mono (possibly changing the value type).
```

Which another Mono is meant there?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`Mono#flatMap` takes a `Function` that transforms a value into another `Mono`. That Mono could represent some asynchronous processing, like an HTTP request.

On the other hand, `Mono#map` takes a `Function` that transforms a value of type `T` into *another value, of type `R`*. That transformation is thus done imperatively and synchronously (eg. transforming a `String` into an `URL` instance).

The other subtlety with `flatMap` is that the operator subscribes to the generated `Mono`, unlike what would happen if you passed the same `Function` to `map`.

Comment: does it mean that if I use `Mono#map` the transformation will be applied immediately without waiting for a subscription? And with `Mono#flatMap` it will be executed first after a subscriber is there? 

I don't really understand why would I need to create a new `Mono` with flatMap.

Comment: Another question, am I right, that `Mono#map, #flatMap` doesn't have directly to do with the `java.util.stream.Stream`'s `#map` and `#flatMap`?

Comment: they do relate to `Stream` methods! `Stream#flatMap` collects the values from the inner streams and flattens them in the resulting `Stream`. In reactive types, the "collecting" part implies subscribing. The only difference is that in `Mono#flatMap` there is only at most one value to flatten, so a closer method would be `Mono#flatMapMany` (which results in a `Flux`)

Comment: The bottom line, your transformation function inside Mono#flatmap should return a Publisher (Mono) for flatMap operator to subscribe to. This is the syntactical difference. The other main (more imp) diff is that if your transformational function involves blocking calls, you are better off using flatMap so that the Publisher it returns can continue the async processing under the hood making your pipeline end to end async. On the other hand, the map will just block the thread thereby affecting the pipeline's async behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it simply,

```
map(a -> b) is returning Mono.just(b)
```

map wraps the returned value in another mono whereas flatmap already expects a Mono do no further wrapping required

Practical use case example,

```
public Mono<String> getResponseFromServer(Mono<String> request) {
    // here few logics
    request.flatMap(r -> callServer(r);
}
```

Where callServer looks like

```
public Mono<String> callServer(String body) {
    // invoke http
    return http call returned mono
}
```

Above use case is not possible with map.

Comment: Note missing right-parenthesis. Presumably should be:
`request.flatMap(r -> callServer(r));`

Comment: This take is very wrong. It is not just a utility method that wraps the result in a Mono. map executes the code synchrounously, whereas flatMap executes it asynchronously.