# Retrieving Mono<T> without blocking

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

My goal is pretty simple, but unfortunately, Im totaly newbie in reactive programming:

having `Mono <User> mono` how to get User in easiest way without blocking threads?

Comment: you can't thats the whole purpose. Think of it as a future. If you are a total newbie then stack overflow is not the place to ask questions. You should instead learn reactive programming from all the documentation out there on the web. Stack Overflow should be your last resort. Please use google. https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/

Comment: Well, let me clarify my view on the problem: lets say I build utility class with method to convert Mono<Object> as argument and return Object , on every doOnNext( reading Object's field and set to newly created one ) ,finally subcribe()? Is it a code smell or not?

Comment: Of course Im gonna go deep into reactive programming , but sometimes we all have no time to learn(.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63106428/spring-webflux-extracting-object-from-mono-without-block

Comment: no time, is not a reason to not first use google or search stack overflow before asking

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally subscribed on Mono method and retrieved its values through lambda. To all who just started, don't try to extract it by blocking.